# BASH script, !=: command not found

Tags: bash, symbol-not-found

Getting the error above when running my script.  Trying to check if the value of output is not = to "average:".  If not, then print to list file, if it is then start from beginning of loop.

```
#!/bin/bash

Oad=$(date +%Y_%m_%d.%H.%M.%S)

for i in {1..120}
do
OUTP= uptime | awk '{print $10}' | cut -f1 -d, 
echo $OUTP
if $OUTP != average:
   then $OUTP >> $Oad.lst
else continue;
fi
sleep 60
done
cat $Oad.lst | awk '{if(min==""){min=max=$1}; if($1>max) {max=$1}; if($1<min) {min=$1}; total+=$1; count+=1} END {print total/count, max, min}' > $Oad.out
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not the way to compare it.

```
if $OUTP != average:
```

Should be

```
if [[ $OUTP != average: ]]
```

Some line seemed odd as well

```
OUTP= uptime | awk '{print $10}' | cut -f1 -d,
```

I think should be

```
OUTP=$(uptime | awk '{print $10}' | cut -f1 -d,)
```

And

```
then $OUTP >> $Oad.lst
```

if you want to send the value of the variable to the file, it should be

```
then echo "$OUTP" >> "$Oad.lst"
```

Overall I would suggest a format like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

Oad=$(date +%Y_%m_%d.%H.%M.%S)

for i in {1..120}; do
    OUTP=$(uptime | awk '{print $10}' | cut -f1 -d,)
    echo "$OUTP"
    if [[ $OUTP != average: ]]; then
        echo "$OUTP" >> "$Oad.lst"
        sleep 60
    fi
done

awk '{if(min==""){min=max=$1}; if($1>max) {max=$1}; if($1<min) {min=$1}; total+=$1; count+=1} END {print total/count, max, min}' "$Oad.lst" > "$Oad.out"
```

One more note. For:

```
    if [[ $OUTP != average: ]]; then
```

You probably mean it as:

```
    if [[ $OUTP != *average:* ]]; then
```

To match any line not containing `average:` instead of any line that's not exactly like it.

Comment: Thanks. Works just like I wanted it to.

Answer (score 2):

This is just a side comment to augment @konsolebox' answer, but it might be better still to do all of the logic in a single Awk script.

```
#!/bin/bash

Oad=$(date +%Y_%m_%d.%H.%M.%S)

for i in {1..120}
do
    uptime
    sleep 60
done |

awk '$10 != "average" { t=$10; sub(/,.*/,"",t);
         if(min=="") min=max=t;
         if(t>max) max=t;
         if(t<min) min=t;
         total += t; count++ }
    END {print total/count, max, min}' > $Oad.out
```

This requires some refactoring if you also want the intermediate results in `$Oad.lst`, but it's not an intrusive change.  (Just print in the main loop, and open a second file handle in the `END` loop.)